# Detect if current connection is metered without NetworkManager

Tags: networking, terminal, systemd-networkd

Along with other developer I am creating a script to automatically update Linux systems as long as they are not connected to metered connections.

But we have found that some systems would use "systemd-networkd" instead of network-manager for configuring the network, and having both programs will conflict with each other.

So we can't really rely on nmcli being installed on the system, and using the solutions of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43228973/detect-if-current-connection-is-metered-with-networkmanager).

Comment: Can you use `busctl`?

Comment: Yes, what for??

Comment: In that case, you may be interested in [this answer using `busctl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54481683/247696)

Answer (score 6):

There is no single sure way to automatically detect that. There are some ways for the network to give a hint that it's metered, but those methods are nowhere near ubiquitously deployed.

- An Android device acting as a WiFi hotspot or a tethering device will set DHCP option 43 to string `ANDROID_METERED`, and will force that option to be returned in a DHCP response. See: https://www.lorier.net/docs/android-metered.html
- [Apple apparently has its own way to indicate connection status to clients using the hotspot functionality of an iOS device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/199163), although information seems to be scarce.
- A WiFi base station may implement a Microsoft-designed [802.11 protocol extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/fi-fi/windows-hardware/drivers/mobilebroadband/network-cost-information-element) to indicate the metered status of the wireless network. In Linux, I assume `wpa_supplicant` would probably be the component to receive this information.
- If no other information is present, Windows sets the default value of the "metered connection" attribute based on just the connection type (Ethernet, WiFi, 4G, 3G, or default/unknown): see https://www.msoutlook.info/question/metered-network-warning

But when those hints are not present, you cannot assume that the connection is not metered; it might or might not be. With NetworkManager, the "metered connection" attribute can be set by the user when configuring the connection, since the user may best know the status of the connection.

So, you might just give the user the choice/responsibility to either run your script or to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

As @telcoM stated, there is no sure way to determine whether a connection is metered. An additional option would be to set-up a table of known connections and whether or not they are metered. A relatively good indicator for this is the external IP address, which you can determine with

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution we found still requirest Network Manager:

```bash
nmcli --terse --fields GENERAL.METERED dev show 2>/dev/null | grep --quiet "yes"
```

Comment: The question asks for a solution *without* Network Manager.

Comment: Yes, but on all this time nobody provided a solution that does so.

Comment: OK, but if that makes a Network Manager-based solution acceptable, you should edit your question to say so, or give more context in your answer.

Comment: Sounds like those extra checks are redundant, `nmcli --terse --fields GENERAL.METERED dev show 2> /dev/null | grep -q yes` would be enough unless you want to see some errors by nmcli in the case where it's installed and nm running and nmcli still fails for some reason.

Comment: See also `systemctl -q is-active NetworkManager.service` to check that the service is running.

Comment: What if `nmcli` is available by not in `/usr/bin`. `if command -v nmcli > /dev/null 2>&1` may be more appropriate.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Won't it be necessary to at least check if the service is running, just to warrant that network manager is installed and running?

Comment: @AlbertoSalviaNovella, I'd expect `nmcli` to fail just the same in that case. Would also  fail if it's not installed. In the end the check is can nmcli tell me the connection is metered.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah, I see 